# SSLCertVerificationError with MQTT on windows

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, mqtt, paho

This is my code

```
client = mqtt.Client(Client_id)
client.tls_set()
client.username_pw_set(username=usename,
                       password=password)
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect(Broker, Port, Keep_Alive)
client.loop_forever()
```

Then I got this error

```
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1129)
```

This code work a few past week ago but now it suddenly error and i don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

`certificate verify failed: certificate has expired`

The error message is pretty clear.

If the certificate the broker is presenting has expired between when it worked and now that would clearly explain the problem.

You need to talk to who ever runs the broker and get them to update the certificate with a valid one.

As a **temporary** workaround you can use the `tls_insecure_set()` function to disable server certificate checking. But understand that is will basically make TLS useless as anybody could now impersonate the broker you are trying to connect to.

https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/python/docs/index.php#tls-insecure-set

Comment: but if i run a code on the other computer. It's can be run without an error

Comment: Firstly that information should have been in the original question. Secondly that probably means the clock is wrong on the machine it fails on.

Comment: Sorry for did not give all information in the question. How do i check and fix for the clock on machine?

Comment: That is a separate question, probably better asked on SuperUser